# Jquery Datepicker ToDate Greater than Or Equal To FromDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

i have a requirement in which i need to two date pickers for entering from and To Dates.ToDate Should be greater than or equal to From Date(After selecting fromdate,all previous dates should be disabled in second Datepiker).Also both from date and todate should be from current Year only.How can i do the same using jquery date picker configuration.Current i am creating date pikers like this

```
     $(document).on('click', '#From', function () {
    $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', changeMonth: true, yearRange: new Date().getFullYear().toString() + ':' + new Date().getFullYear().toString(), changeYear: false });
});

$(document).on('click', '#To', function () {
    $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', changeMonth: true, yearRange: new Date().getFullYear().toString() + ':' + new Date().getFullYear().toString(), changeYear: false });
});
```

Can anyone help on this

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range - this does what you want I believe

Comment: did this work for you? please accept and answer below or answer your own question so others can see how you did it. They may have the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to do this without losing the year restriction is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
            $("#From").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                changeMonth: true,
                yearRange: new Date().getFullYear().toString() + ':' + new Date().getFullYear().toString(),
                onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                    $("#To").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                }
            });
            $("#To").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                changeMonth: true,
                yearRange: new Date().getFullYear().toString() + ':' + new Date().getFullYear().toString(),
                onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                    $("#From").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```